# Is it possible to `splice()` from a socket to a buffer with "zero-copy"?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

Is it possible to [`splice()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) from a socket to a buffer with "zero-copy"? If yes, how?

---

The example code I found for [`splice()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) has two steps ([splice example code](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/06/01/zero-copy-in-linux-with-sendfile-and-splice/)):

1. splice from socket to pipe
2. splice from pipe to file descriptor

Is there always going to be an intermediary step of using a pipe (i.e. you can't do a zero-copy operation into a buffer in user space)?

Comment: If you want zero copy why not just read the data directly instead of using `splice`?

Comment: Err, `splice()` copies between file descriptors. It doesn't have anything to do with buffers. If you want your own buffer you can't have zero-copy. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: splice() is for transferring data between 2 file descriptors in 2 steps (e.g. from a socket to pipe, and then from the pipe to a socket) using zero-copy(if feasible), not for transferring data to or from a buffer in your own program.

Comment: Yes it has to be through `pipe(2)`, because you can't copy from kernel to a user space buffer.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of `splice()`.  Its Linux manual page describes it this way: "splice - splice data to/from **a pipe**" (emphasis added).  If you are instead trying to put the data into a buffer then using `splice()` instead of `recvfrom()` is more work to achieve exactly the same result.

Comment: "get data to your buffer" and "zero-copy" hardly coexist

Comment: @user3159253 the `splice()`/`pipe(2)` combination outperforms a simple `read(2)`/`recvfrom(2)`. Using a simple read, buffer has to be copied from kernel to user space before anything. Using splice, data gets copied one time :).

Comment: http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/splice.html this thread explain the reasons why you have to use a `pipe()`. Very interesting, explained by Linus Torvalds. Hope it helps.

Comment: Given that getting from socket to a user-space buffer "with zero-copy" may not be possible, I changed the question to ask first "if possible... if yes, how?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@yeyo has answer this question in the question's comments IMO but did not provide a timely answer. So I will summarize:

**You can not `splice()` from a socket to a buffer with “zero-copy”.**

---

The reason you can't use `splice()` is because `splice()` "[requires either the source or destination to be a pipe](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/splice.html)". In other words when the source is a socket then the destination must be a pipe because of the API's restrictions ('either the source or destination or both must be a pipe').

---

That answers the yes or no question but not the "why".

I still had questions about the "why" or specifically:

- "Why does splice() require the source or destination to be a pipe?"
- and
- "Why can't I splice directly from a socket to user memory?"

Linus Torvalds answers those questions directly in the link and his answer seems clear and concise to me (if not with a little studying of what he writes): http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/splice.html

Comment: Just because you can't use splice to achieve zero-copy doesn't mean you can't do zero-copy from a socket. *(1.)* One method that is not zero-copy (but order of magnitude less than recv/recvfrom) is to use `recvmmsg()` (NOTE: there are two 'm' in that... not a misspelling (see `man recvmmsg`)). *(2.)* true zero-copy is achieved using [packet_mmap](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt) but the API is complex/tricky and requires special permissions to run